# Laravel TestCase can't run the next request

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test my Laravel controller but the second time doing a request:

```
$this->call('GET', "api/school");
```

always returns:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
```

But the first time it's fine. Can I call `$this->call` multiple times in my test methods? I don't want to duplicate the code if that's the case, is there a way to nest the test code like Rspec context does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call's address is being appended to the first one.

`$this->call()` calls method `request()` in `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client`, which in turn calls `getAbsoluteUri()`.

The interesting thing is `getAbsoluteUri()` causes your test to call `/api/school/api/school` the second time. Here's the description of getAbsoluteUri() from [symfony's source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php#L546).

> Takes a URI and converts it to absolute if it is not already absolute.

And looking from the source code, it seems like it takes your previous call, and append the new one to it if your second request is not an absolute URI already.

So to fix this, you must make sure the call() gets your absolute URI already, simply do:

```
 $this->call('GET', "/api/school");
```

Comment: Thanks for the extremely detailed and helpful answer. I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior or a bug.

Comment: @randomor I would say it is the intended behavior. The BrowserKit client being used by Laravel actually simulates itself as a web browser. So the same way if you are on `http://yourweb.com/api/school` in your browser and you click on a `<a href="api/school">`, it would send you to `http://yourweb.com/api/school/api/school`. (I didn't know before that the little `$this->call()` is that powerful too!)